# Conjugacy classes in normalized unit group of a group ring

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-number-theory, computer-algebra, gap

Let $V(FA_4)$ be the normalized unit group of the group ring $FA_4$, where $F$ is the field containing 4 elements and $A_4$ is the alternating group on 4 symbols. How can I find conjugacy classes of elements of $V$ using GAP commands? (Since GAP has mostly commands for $p$-groups over a finite field $F_p$.)